# Flatten and restructure linq in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq

I want to restructure the original **json data with a list of trips** and **return a converted and flatten list** based on the **boarding points** and the **dropping points** using **Linq**. Below is the example of original json data and the result that I want. How do I do that? Please help. Thanks.

Original Json:

```
[{
     tripId: 1,
     name: "abc express",
     boardingTimes: [
     {
         time: 1200,
         id: 12,
         name: "A"
     },
     {
         time: 1215,
         id: 14,
         name: "B"
     }
     ],
     droppingTimes: [{
         time: 1400,
         id: 15,
         name: "C"
     }]
}]
```

Result:

```
[{
         tripId: 1,
         name: "abc express",
         boardingTimes: 
         {
             time: 1200,
             id: 12,
             name: "A"
         },
         droppingTimes: {
             time: 1400,
             id: 15,
             name: "C"
         }
},
         tripId: 1,
         name: "abc express",
         boardingTimes: 
         {
             time: 1215,
             id: 14,
             name: "B"
         },
         droppingTimes: {
             time: 1400,
             id: 15,
             name: "C"
         }
]
```

Comment: I was stuck back then, have tried a few times using linq but so far no result has been useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) which is part of [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
JArray trips = JArray.Parse(originalJson);

JArray pairs = new JArray(trips
    .Select(trip => 
        new JArray(trip["boardingTimes"]
            .Join(trip["droppingTimes"], bt => 1, dt => 1, (bt, dt) => 
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("tripId", trip["tripId"]),
                    new JProperty("name", trip["name"]),
                    new JProperty("boardingTimes", bt),
                    new JProperty("droppingTimes", dt)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .SelectMany(a => a)
);

string flattenedJson = pairs.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VN1AGM

Comment: Thanks, @Brian Rogers. Your solution solves my problem. But, I am confused why `bt => 1` and `dt => 1` will get the correct **boardingTimes** and **droppingTimes**? What does **1** represents?

Comment: In the `Join` method, the second and third parameters are lambda functions which retrieve the keys for the objects that we want to join on in the two respective lists. So, for example, if we wanted to match `boardingTime.id` with `droppingTime.id` we would use `bt => bt.id` and `dt => dt.id` lambda functions, respectively. But in this case, there are no keys to match on; the ids don't correspond with each other. Instead, we want to match ALL boarding times with ALL dropping times in each trip. So, I just made the lambda functions return a "key" that will always match no matter what, i.e. 1.